# Parse HTTP directory listing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Good day! I'm using Delphi XE and Indy TIdHTTP. Using Get method I get remote directory listing and I need to parse it = get list of files with their sizes and timestamps and distinguish files and subdirectories. Please, is there a good routine to do that? Thank you in advance! Vojtech

Here is the sample:

```
<head>
  <title>127.0.0.1 - /</title>
</head>
<body>
  <H1>127.0.0.1 - /</H1><hr>
<pre>      
  Mittwoch, 30. März 2011    12:01        &lt;dir&gt; <A HREF="/SubDir/">SubDir</A><br />
  Mittwoch, 9. Februar 2005    17:14          113 <A HREF="/file.txt">file.txt</A><br />
</pre>
<hr>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample? There isn't really a standard "directory listing" (well, actually, there are *several*, depending on the server and the OS it's running on), and without knowing which you're working with it's hard to tell what you might need to do.

Comment: what you need is an HTML parser that creates a tree, so it would be easy to find all "A" tags and act according to your needs.

Comment: If the server supports WebDAV a more robust solution would be easy to implement with a WebDAV client library. Every server version update or software change would break a parser specific for this HTML output.

Comment: @DorinDuminica, I was also thinking about a DOM "parser". take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9418636/937125). but I think that in this case it's an overkill. so I'm with @Cosmin Prund (+1 BTW), specially if every line in the `pre` tag is `TAB` delimited (`TStringList` would do just fine).

Comment: @kobik an overkill? I don't think so, mainly because if the parser is even a bit optimized it would be very fast, if using Pos() or something similar search, it can easily break later, and usually things break when you have little time to fix...

Comment: @DorinDuminica, actually after thinking it over I realized that you might be right. :) `getAdjacentText` did the job well. so I posted my answer as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the code sample, I guess the *fastest* way to parse it would be like this:

- Identify the `<pre>...</pre>` block containing all the listing lines. Should be easy.
- Put everything between the `<pre>` and `</pre>` into a `TStringList`. Each line is a file or  folder, and the format is very simple.
- Extract the links from each line, extract the date, time and size if you need it. Best done with a regex (you've got Delphi XE so you've got built-in Regex).

Comment: +1. It's easy when you have a sample. Aren't you glad I asked? :)

Answer (score 7):

This should give you a good start and idea using DOM:

```
uses
  MSHTML,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

procedure DocumentFromString(Document: IHTMLDocument2; const S: WideString);
var
  v: OleVariant;
begin
  v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
  v[0] := S;
  Document.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray));
  Document.Close;
end;

function StripMultipleChar(const S: string; const C: Char): string;
begin
  Result := S;
  while Pos(C + C, Result) <> 0 do
    Result := StringReplace(Result, C + C, C, [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;
  Elements: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Element: IHTMLElement;
  I: Integer;
  Line: string;
begin
  Document := CreateComObject(CLASS_HTMLDocument) as IHTMLDocument2;
  DocumentFromString(Document, '<head>...'); // your HTML here

  Elements := Document.all.tags('A') as IHTMLElementCollection;
  for I := 0 to Elements.length - 1 do
  begin
    Element := Elements.item(I, '') as IHTMLElement;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('A HREF=' + Element.getAttribute('HREF', 2));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('A innerText=' + Element.innerText);

    // Text is returned immediately before the element
    Line := (Element as IHTMLElement2).getAdjacentText('beforeBegin');

    // Line => "Mittwoch, 30. März 2011 12:01 <dir>" OR:
    // Line => "Mittwoch, 9. Februar 2005 17:14 113"...
    // I don't know what is the actual delimiter:
    // It could be [space] or [tab] so we need to normalize the Line
    // If it's tabs then it's easier because the timestamps also contains spaces

    Line := Trim(Line);
    Line := StripMultipleChar(Line, #32); // strip multiple Spaces sequences
    Line := StripMultipleChar(Line, #9);  // strip multiple Tabs sequences

    // TODO: ParseLine (from right to left)

    Memo1.Lines.Add(Line);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('-------------');
  end;
end;
```

---

Output:

```
A HREF=/SubDir/
A innerText=SubDir
Mittwoch, 30. März 2011 12:01 <dir>
-------------
A HREF=/file.txt
A innerText=file.txt
Mittwoch, 9. Februar 2005 17:14 113
-------------
```

---

**EDIT:**
I have changed `StripMultipleChar` implementation to be more *simplified*. yet I belive the former version was more *optimized* to speed. considering the fact that the Lines are very short in length, there will be no much differences in performance.

Comment: +1 because it would work. The `StripMultipleChar` could be simplified a bit.

Comment: it can be *simplified* and *optimized*. You've got so many *while* loops in there it makes my head spin: all you need is a single, straight-forward for loop.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, See my edit. the former function was actually based on one of the JCL units...